# Error during URL to PDF converter script in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdfkit

I am creating a script in python which accepts a URL and converts it into PDF.I am using pdfkit Library which is working well. But I have a problem during this conversion to PDF. On some web pages, some images are being loaded and some were not. And navigation bars also not loading in PDF. Could you please tell me where I doing wrong?

Thanks

Here, is my code.

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_url('https://www.nu.edu.pk','Fast.pdf')
```

Comment: Does the library run JavaScript code?

Comment: Besides, the question is not self-contained (it depends on the web page being available)

Comment: Yes! it runs javascript code. How to come up with not available web pages?